# Using radio buttons

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I'm doing a security check with my radio buttons, and it's returning an error even though I don't think there should be. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is the class to update

```
public function set ($iStatus)
{
    $this->iStatus = $iStatus;
}
public function create ()
{
    if ($this->iStatus != 0 || $this->iStatus != 1 || $this->iStatus != 2)
    {
        echo "Your idea must have a valid status";
    }
    else
    {
        //update the database
    }
}
```

and then the html form

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $class->set($_POST["status"]);
    $class->create();
}
else
{
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" checked/> 
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" /> 
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" /> 
}
```

And it returns the error valid status. I figured maybe inputs save everything as strings or chars so I redid the error checking to say

```
if ($this->iStatus != '0') { /*blah*/ }
```

but that didn't work either. So I am confused

Comment: A silly question, are you sure the form is of type POST and not GET? What do you get if you replace $_POST with $_REQUEST?

Comment: no it is post, i like the thinking outside of the box though. I have other fields in the form that work fine, but when I added these radio buttons it wouldn't submit after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic is backwards:

```
if ($this->iStatus != 0 || $this->iStatus != 1 || $this->iStatus != 2)
```

should be:

```
if ($this->iStatus != 0 && $this->iStatus != 1 && $this->iStatus != 2)
```

full test:

```
<?php
class foo{
    private $iStatus;

    public function set($iStatus){
        $this->iStatus = $iStatus;
    }
    public function create(){
        if ($this->iStatus != 0 && $this->iStatus != 1 && $this->iStatus != 2){
            echo "Your idea must have a valid status";
        }else{
            echo "All good";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $class = new foo;
    $class->set($_POST["status"]);
    $class->create();
}else{
    echo '
    <form method="post" action="./">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1"> 
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>';
}?>
```

Comment: thanks! you're right I changed the comparison operators from == to != and forgot to change the logical operators too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the error is in the if statement. You should substitute the || with &&

otherwise you will always get the error message

Because even if it is 0 your if statement returns true because != 1 is true

Comment: it's not a php error, just the error that i have "Your idea must have a valid status", and i tried it, still the same issue

Comment: when you print the value of $iStatus what do you get?

Comment: i get a 0, so yeah i don't know what going on

Comment: the error is in the if statement. You should substitute the || with &&

Comment: ah! you're right, my logic was off, i changed them from == when i was testing it before, to != and forgot to update the logical operators. Thanks!